# Display steam inventory using php and api

Tags: php, json, steam

At the moment im getting a json reponse when i query [http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_{appid}/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key={apikey}&steamid={steamid}&format=json](http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_%7Bappid%7D/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=%7Bapikey%7D&steamid=%7Bsteamid%7D&format=json)

The problem however is that i dont know what to do with this reponse without any aditional info that i cant find anywhere. A part of response im getting when looking at my own cs:go inventory:

```
            {
            "id": 235322185,
            "original_id": 190991409,
            "defindex": 19,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 4,
            "inventory": 70,
            "quantity": 1,
            "rarity": 4,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 6,
                    "value": 1130627072,
                    "float_value": 228
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 7,
                    "value": 1148436480,
                    "float_value": 975
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 8,
                    "value": 1031063904,
                    "float_value": 0.059762358665466309
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 147,
                    "value": "models\/weapons\/stattrack.mdl"
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 145,
                    "value": "models\/weapons\/w_smg_p90_mag.mdl"
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "id": 236527226,
            "original_id": 236502674,
            "defindex": 27,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 9,
            "inventory": 82,
            "quantity": 1,
            "rarity": 3,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 6,
                    "value": 1133608960,
                    "float_value": 291
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 7,
                    "value": 1142240880,
                    "float_value": 596.8505859375
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 8,
                    "value": 994750258,
                    "float_value": 0.0030927178449928761
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 80,
                    "value": 0,
                    "float_value": 0
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 81,
                    "value": 0,
                    "float_value": 0
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 147,
                    "value": "models\/weapons\/stattrack.mdl"
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 145,
                    "value": "models\/weapons\/w_shot_mag7_mag.mdl"
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            "id": 236529059,
            "original_id": 136971214,
            "defindex": 35,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 4,
            "inventory": 77,
            "quantity": 1,
            "rarity": 2,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 6,
                    "value": 1077936128,
                    "float_value": 3
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 7,
                    "value": 1141712676,
                    "float_value": 564.611572265625
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 8,
                    "value": 1031160533,
                    "float_value": 0.060122329741716385
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 147,
                    "value": "models\/weapons\/stattrack.mdl"
                }
            ]

        }
```

The id's correnspond with the weapons and the rarity and quantity makes sense too. But i cant be expected to manually find every id of every weapon in every state right? Am i missing a different API that i can use to see what weapon corrensponds with what id?

ps: Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will call the [GetSchema](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetSchema) to determine which items these are. You'll compare DefIndex values against the ones returned by `GetSchema`

Your work flow will look like this:

- Call `GetSchema` and store result of `result['items']` some place to look up later
- Call your current call and parse through the items. For each item, look up a result in your stored value from above
- `GetSchema` also has rarities and other values you may need (ie. those attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Compare your inventory *defindex* (not attributes) value with this schema.

http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetSchema/v0002/?key=xxxxx

For example,defindex = 19 is weapon_p90 on schema.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution aswell

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse JSON strings into an array. Because this response is not totaly a valid JSON string try to insert this into a new array to parse a valid JSON string.

Such as: **{"main_container": [**   --> YOUR POSTED CODE <--   **]}**

```
<?php

    $jsonResponse = '{"main_container": [
                {
                "id": 235322185,
                "original_id": 190991409,
                "defindex": 19,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 4,
                "inventory": 70,
                "quantity": 1,
                "rarity": 4,
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "defindex": 6,
                        "value": 1130627072,
                        "float_value": 228
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 7,
                        "value": 1148436480,
                        "float_value": 975
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 8,
                        "value": 1031063904,
                        "float_value": 0.059762358665466309
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 147,
                        "value": "models\/weapons\/stattrack.mdl"
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 145,
                        "value": "models\/weapons\/w_smg_p90_mag.mdl"
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                "id": 236527226,
                "original_id": 236502674,
                "defindex": 27,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 9,
                "inventory": 82,
                "quantity": 1,
                "rarity": 3,
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "defindex": 6,
                        "value": 1133608960,
                        "float_value": 291
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 7,
                        "value": 1142240880,
                        "float_value": 596.8505859375
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 8,
                        "value": 994750258,
                        "float_value": 0.0030927178449928761
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 80,
                        "value": 0,
                        "float_value": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 81,
                        "value": 0,
                        "float_value": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 147,
                        "value": "models\/weapons\/stattrack.mdl"
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 145,
                        "value": "models\/weapons\/w_shot_mag7_mag.mdl"
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                "id": 236529059,
                "original_id": 136971214,
                "defindex": 35,
                "level": 1,
                "quality": 4,
                "inventory": 77,
                "quantity": 1,
                "rarity": 2,
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "defindex": 6,
                        "value": 1077936128,
                        "float_value": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 7,
                        "value": 1141712676,
                        "float_value": 564.611572265625
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 8,
                        "value": 1031160533,
                        "float_value": 0.060122329741716385
                    },
                    {
                        "defindex": 147,
                        "value": "models\/weapons\/stattrack.mdl"
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]}
    ';

    $jsonDecodeArray = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

    foreach($jsonDecodeArray as $mainContainerItems){

        // LOOP THROUGH ALL ITEM GROUP. IN THIS CASE WE HAVE 3 ITEM GROUPS IN
        // $mainContainerItems ARRAY

        foreach($mainContainerItems as $inventoryItem){

            echo $inventoryItem['id']; // will return for example: 236529059
            echo $inventoryItem['original_id']; // will return for example: 136971214
            echo $inventoryItem['defindex'];
        }       
    }
?>
```

In this case the resoult will be a multi dimensional array, where you can loop through with multiple foreach.

The resoult is:

***$jsonDecodeArray*** contains the **main_container** array with all items, where a single item is also an array.

***$inventoryItem*** contains a single item with it's all properties. Like shown below.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 236529059
    [original_id] => 136971214
    [defindex] => 35
    [level] => 1
    [quality] => 4
    [inventory] => 77
    [quantity] => 1
    [rarity] => 2
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [defindex] => 6
                    [value] => 1077936128
                    [float_value] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [defindex] => 7
                    [value] => 1141712676
                    [float_value] => 564.61157226562
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [defindex] => 8
                    [value] => 1031160533
                    [float_value] => 0.060122329741716
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [defindex] => 147
                    [value] => models/weapons/stattrack.mdl
                )

        )

)
```